# Reading username and password from a text file and comparing them to textfields won't work eventhough they are the exact same

Tags: java, authentication

I need to create a login/register app that stores and retrieves users info from a file(.txt). So I am comparing the username and password from my file with the username and password from my textfields and eventhough they are the exact same the programm still will not match them.

It was working at some point but that was when I only had the `Login` class. After I finished the `Register` class it would not work eventhough I did not change anything in the `Login` class. I also tried to handwrite the txt just as I did the first time but no luck.

**`Login` class:**

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

class Login extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    JButton SUBMIT;
    JPanel panel;
    JLabel label1, label2;
    final JTextField text1, text2;

    Login() {
        label1 = new JLabel();
        label1.setText("Username:");
        text1 = new JTextField(15);

        label2 = new JLabel();
        label2.setText("Password:");
        text2 = new JPasswordField(15);

        SUBMIT = new JButton("SUBMIT");

        panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(3, 1));
        panel.add(label1);
        panel.add(text1);
        panel.add(label2);
        panel.add(text2);
        panel.add(SUBMIT);
        add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        SUBMIT.addActionListener(this);
        setTitle("LOGIN FORM");
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        File loginf = new File("filename.txt");

        try {
            Scanner read = new Scanner(loginf);
            read.useDelimiter("\\n|,");
            boolean login = false;
            while (read.hasNext()) {
                String user = read.next();
                String pass = read.next();
                String thisuser = text1.getText();
                String thispass = text2.getText();
                System.out.println(user + " " + pass);
                System.out.println(thisuser + " " + thispass);
                if (thisuser.equals(user) && thispass.equals(pass)) {
                    System.out.println("OOOKKKK");
                    login = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (login) {
                NextPage page = new NextPage();
                page.setVisible(true);
                JLabel label = new JLabel("Welcome:" + text1.getText());
                page.getContentPane().add(label);
                setVisible(false);
            } else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Incorrect username or password");
                text1.setText("");
                text2.setText("");
            }
            read.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException qwerty) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Can't find a text file");
        }
    }

}
```

**Parts of the `Register` class that I am using:**

```
ln95: FileWriter out = null;
ln98: out = new FileWriter("filename.txt", true);


ln149:out.write(username + "," + pass);
ln150:out.write(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
```

**Output from login:**

```
student1 Student1
student2 Student2    
student2 Student2
student2 Student2    
student3 Student3
student2 Student2
```

Comment: Really strange; enclose you debug code to quotes - just to be sure there aren't white spaces; System.out.println("'" + user + "' '" + pass + "'"); and update output.

Answer (score 0):

The output that you have listed from login seems to have an extra carriage return that's why there seems to be an empty line. I assume this is coming from following piece of code.

```
            System.out.println(user + " " + pass);
            System.out.println(thisuser + " " + thispass);
```

If that is the case then `thispass` has one extra carriage return. That is causing the problem.

Comment: Thank you for yoyr answer,
I indeed followed other pieces of code but I did not really get what are you suggesting that I change, can you please explain further?
Thank you

Comment: If this is the problem then you can check by simply trying `trim()` for both sides to clear any spaces and carriages like below:
`if(thisuser.trim().equals(user.trim()) && thispass.trim().equals(pass.trim()))`